# spatial interpolation using Ordinary Kriging

Tags: geospatial, spatial, kriging

Two different institutions are using the same dataset for spatial interpolation using Ordinary Kriging. However, the resulting maps shows deviances.What are the potential causes of differences in maps?

Answer (score 0):

Some options which come to mind would be:

- Variogram fit parameter differences
- Neighborhood radius limit
- Interpolated grid density (if interpolating into a grid)

Also, you may have better luck on gis.stackexchange.com, and I’d recommend you include a minimal publishable example and whatever other details you can find (what softwares/libraries in which company, etc).